# How do we provide valuable feedback on rejected edits to editors?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have noticed an uptick in edits regarding major code changes or radical changes to the post. For habitual editors, should we display a warning and altogether prevent them from editing (like we do for flagging) if there are too many consecutive rejected edits? For instance, after 3 consecutive rejected edits, it should redirect you to a page about proper editing guidelines due to the 3 consecutive rejected edits. The user should have to demonstrate they understand how to properly edit by passing editing tests before being allowed to edit again.

Answer (score 2):

Users are *already* prevented from submitting edits if they have a certain number of recent rejected edits.  It's not based on consecutive rejections, but rather amount of rejections over a short period of time.

Comment: Eh, maybe it needs to be tweaked to encompass consecutive and time because if they don't edit that often they may not see the warning or block

Comment: If they're very rarely suggesting edits then they're not causing a significant problem.  One or two bad edits a week isn't exactly a huge drain.  Dozens of bad edits a day is.  And given the very, very poor quality of the reviewers, a *huge* number of bad suggested edits actually get approved.  When someone submits 50 bad suggested edits it's actually quite common to see half of them approved, and I could easily see there never being a streak of 3 consecutive rejections, even if there are 20 rejection in 10 minutes.  The really harmful situations are covered best by the current system.

Comment: @Servy, Slightly off-topic: Do you know if submitted edits that have not yet been voted on or had their review completed yet are affected by such a trigger? *Hypothetical e.g.*: **1.** User submits 100 edits. **2.** Edits are reviewed in order submitted. **3.** By suggestion #40, 20 have been rejected and trigger this warning/edit permission revoke. **4.** I assume the user cannot submit any extra edit suggestions at that point but are the remaining 60 edits in the queue affected? All declined, all remain in the review queue as normal, all silently removed/deleted etc.

Comment: @indivisible Pretty sure they aren't automatically rejected, although they should be.  (Or, for that matter, the better solution is to simply put a limit on the max number of pending suggested edits a single user can have, to prevent the situation from ever coming up in the first place.)